# Can I fertilize my plants after putting pesticide?

Tags: fertilizer, pesticide, vermicomposting

I have a problem with my plants; they have mealybugs, aphids and fungi. Tonight I sprayed them with agricultural pesticide, also cutting the infected branches and even exterminated some plants.

I wanted to know how they could be stronger (because I use strong chemicals and I hope this kills the plague). Can I give them fertilizer the next night, and can I put vermicompost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes of course you can fertilize them after you put all those pesticide on them.

But next time, you must fertilize them **before** anything bad happen to them! I know and am sorry it is too late.

In fact, most plants get diseases and attract pests because they are not healthy enough. To avoid having to treat your plants, you should choose plants adapted to your location, and feed them right so that they don't get sick.

But it can be difficult to find the right fertilizer to give them, because it depends of the kind of plants and the season time. Vermicompost on the other hand should do because it contains lots of good nutriments and feeds on the long run.